# Mass has the same value in all inertial reference frames?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, inertial-frames

Is  mass the same in all inertial frames? If it is, why is that? If not, can you also explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is, that's why it's called "rest mass". Every body is at rest in his own inertial frame. In other inertial frames relative to which your mass is moving it also has kinetic energy, and since energy and mass are equivalent there is also the so called "relativistic mass", but when you only say "mass" you usually mean "rest mass" and that is invariant by definition.

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: Uhm. Okay.I can't say I find this at all clear.

Comment: The only difference between your text and mine is that I call it rest mass and you call it proper mass, but as far as I know both are valid words for the same property.

Comment: And does momentum and energy depends on the inertial frame?

Comment: Yes, but that's already the case under Newton, where the kinetic energy $e_k=m v^2/2$. Under Einstein it would be $e_k=m c^2/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}-m c^2$ but the speed $v$ always depends on your system.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the concept of relativistic mass (with no physical meaning) was introduced in order to have relativistic equations with the same form as the classical ones.

Comment: It does have some physical meaning; for example, if you heat up a box by increasing the kinetic energy (and therefore relativistic mass) of its atoms the box will indeed weigh more on a scale, even in its own rest frame (see Q&A #3 at http://bit.ly/1SQOljR) but you're right about the newtonian formalism.

Comment: @СимонТыран While it is true that a hot box has a greater rest mass than a cold box, it is not correct to assign the extra mass to any atom of the box. The rest mass of a system is simply not the sum of the rest masses of the components. The atoms themselves have a smaller mass that the total of the rest masses of the protons, neutrons, and electrons, since energy is released from the atom upon formation. The kinetic energy component of the relativistic mass is frame dependent, so two observers will disagree on which atom is heavier. But, they will agree on the total rest mass of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Mass is 100% about the balance between energy and momentum: $$mc^2=\sqrt{E^2-(\vec pc)^2}.$$

For some systems, the mass is zero. For others it is nonzero. When it is nonzero, the the energy momentum vector points in the same direction as the tangent to the worldline of the particle. And further the energy momentum vector is nothing other than $mc^2$ times the unit tangent to the worldline.

Everyone agrees on the worldline (it's the set of events where the particle is) and everyone agrees on the  tangents to the worldline. And everyone agrees if you have a non null vector you can make a unit vector out of it. And everyone agrees that unit vector and the energy-momentum vector point in the same direction and since $E^2-(\vec pc)^2$ is the squared length of the energy-momentum vector, its length is just $mc^2$.

So we know what mass is, it's the (possibly null) length of the energy-momentum vector, an actual vector in Minkowski spacetime. With an actual length.

So there simply isn't anything to disagree about. The length of a tangent vector doesn't depend on frame, and neither does the length of the energy-momentum vector.

Answer (score -1):

"Why" is a often tough question to answer satisfactorily  in theoretical physics. In this case, mass is constant in inertial reference frames because that's part of how they are defined by special relativity:

> **Special principle of relativity**: *If a system of coordinates K is chosen so that, in relation to it, physical laws hold good in their simplest form, the same laws hold good in relation to any other system of coordinates K' moving in uniform translation relatively to K.*

— Albert Einstein: The foundation of the general theory of relativity, Section A

In special relativity, "mass" generally refers to the rest mass (or invariant mass) of an object, which is the Newtonian mass as measured by an observer moving along with the object.

The rest mass of a particle in inertial frame A will hold in in all inertial frames, as that's the entire point of inertial frames - they do away with the relativistic effects of acceleration.

Comment: Special relativity explicitly deals with the differences in inertial frame in motion with respect to each other.

Comment: dmckee can you give me a better answer then?

Comment: hoping that edit helps.

Comment: The problem I have with this answer is that "mass" is not a physical law. How does the principle dictate that the numerical value of the rest mass is the same?

Comment: Because the rest mass of an object is essentially its the inertial mass of that object at rest - which is to say, the mass which is unaffected by the relativistic effects of acceleration - it's specifically defined so that it can be considered constant. And as newtonian laws (such as F=ma) apply in all reference frames without modification, the mass must definitionally remain constant in these different reference frames. 

One might be tempted to call rest mass an object's "true mass" if that didn't further muddy the waters.